# How does `this`context work in immediately self executing functions?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me what is happening here that causes my properties to be attached to the window object:

```
var MyObject = (function () {    
    this.property1 = "prop1";

    return this;
})();
// window.property1 now exists as well as MyObject.property1
```

Is this the "right" way to do this:

```
var MyObject = (function () {
    var MyObject = {};
    MyObject.property1 = "prop1";

    return MyObject;
})();
// only MyObject.property1 now exists
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are confused about. If you call a function like `foo()`, then `this` refers to `window`. What else do you think it would refer to? What do you expect and why?

Comment: @FelixKling You think Javascript makes sense? It doesn't. You know it, so you're not surprised anymore, but it's not all self-explanatory at all. Don't pretend it is.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, `this` inside IIFE works the same way as in any other function call. An IIFE is nothing special, the function definition and execution are just put in one statement/expression instead of two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling a function. Whether it's anonymous or not, it is a function. Functions have context, the `this` keyword.

You have provided no context, so `window` is used.

Try:

```
var MyObject2 = (function() {
    this.property1 = "prop1";
    return this;
}).call(this);
```

Here you are explicity defining the context as "whatever the current context is" - of course, this may again be `window`, but then again it may not - can't really tell without seeing more code.

Comment: There is no more code.  This is all of it.  I am just trying to figure out how to encapsulate things properly.  The call to .call() is not exactly intuitive.  You say I have provided no context, I assumed the var MyObject = ... part was context.  Can you actually explain whats happening?

Comment: To elaborate a little more... if you want to scope the variable to the function body, just use the var keyword instead of assigning to this.  Alternatively you could bind a context to the function.  e.g. `var property1 = 'prop1';`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: call() made no difference -- everything is still attached to the window object.

Comment: @Felix: yes.  I was under the impression that functions created scope, and "this" "belonged" to that function.  Here I was looking for someone to help explain to me what was happening.  Instead I get condescending replies from people like  you.

Comment: @AndrewLeith Your impression is incorrect, then: scope and context are two different things. You should use the second block of code you gave in your question.

Comment: @andrew: I'm sorry if you perceived  it like this. It seemed you are were confused about why it is `window` even though it is explained in the answer, so I just wanted to ensure that you  read it completely. If you want to learn how `this` works, have a look at the MDN documentation, which is pretty extensive: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. Fwiw, yes functions create scope, but the value of `this` doesn't have anything to do with scope and is determined by how the function is called.

Comment: @felix: what is the explanation why property1 becomes a property of both window AND myobject?

Comment: Because `return this`. `myobject` IS the `window` now.

Comment: @AndrewLeith: You are returning `this`. `myObject === window`. Maybe it is clearer when we split definition and call: `function  func() {  this.property1 = "prop1"; return this; } ; var myObject = func();`.